# how to disable all rows in gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to disable all rows like text-box and drop-down controls in the gridview based on some condition that i set for the gridview.  I have it now where it changes the color but i also want to lock it or disable those controls how can i do that?

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Label lblEndDate = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblStudyEndDate");
            DateTime EndDate = DateTime.Parse(lblEndDate.Text);
            if (EndDate < DateTime.Today)
            {
               //make all rows to read only here.. 

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by Disable?. you want to disable copying contents ?

Comment: no i want to lock the textbox so that no one can type anything so basically make it read only.

Comment: then that would be the `Enabled = false` doesn't look like you're doing that anywhere also what Textbox are you wanting to be readonly you need to be more specific

Comment: have you tried any of :
 dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
dataGridView1.Enabled = false;

Comment: i just updated the code i posted

Comment: only if the condition is met then i want to make it read only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Label lblEndDate = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblStudyEndDate");
            TextBox tbSomeTB = e.Row.FindControl("tbSomeTB") as TextBox;

            DateTime EndDate = DateTime.Parse(lblEndDate.Text);
            if (EndDate < DateTime.Today)
            {
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
                tbSomeTB.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Pretty straight forward, the guys in the comments said it already, here is the code which you clearly already know how to write.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
        Label lblEndDate = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblStudyEndDate");
        TextBox txt_1 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txt_1");
        DropDownList ddl_1 = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1");

        DateTime EndDate = DateTime.Parse(lblEndDate.Text);
        if (EndDate < DateTime.Today)
        {
            txt_1.Enabled = false;
            ddl_1.Enabled = false;
            e.Row.CssClass = "setColorClass"; // css class to set bgcolor , forecolor etc 
        }
    }
}
```